# conversion from long double to long long int

Tags: c++

I have a long double sine and a long long int amp. I am using `<cmath>` and have code as follows:

```
sine = sin(point);
amp  = round(sine * 2^31);
```

Here the variable point is incrementing in 0.009375 intervals. The first line here works fine but on the second I receive this error message:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'long double' and 'int' to binary 'operator^'
```

I'm unsure what this error means and the main request here is 'How can I get around this to get an output integer into the variable amp?'

Comment: `2^31` does not have the meaning you intend nor the operator precedence you intend.  The easy, but less readable way to write that is `((unsigned)1<<31)`

Comment: The * has higher precedence. So you get `(sine * 2) ^ 31` and you can't XOR on double

Comment: What do you think operator `^` does? Hint: It does not mean: "raise to the power of".

Comment: Ah ok I did not know that. So should this be fixed if I just replace 2^31 with 2147483648?

Comment: @PeteBecker, You are right. I immediately edited that as I realized, my intent was not communicated by my first attempt at saying it.

Comment: OK! It's fixed and I now have the numbers I need! Thankyou

Comment: Instead of replacing with `2147483648`, you could use `(1LL << 31)`

Answer (score 2):

In C++ the `^` operator means exclusive or, not exponentiation. You probably meant (`1ULL << 31`).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that `*` is multiplication, and `^` is the bitwise `xor` operator which can only be applied to integral types.

Multiplication (`*`) has higher precedence than `^`.  So the compiler interprets `amp  = round(sine * 2^31);` as `amp = round( (sine *2)^31);`.   `sine` (presumably) has type `long double`, so the result of `sine*2` is also of type `long double`.  `long double` is not an integral type, so cannot be an operand of `^`.   Hence the error.

Your mistake is assuming that `^` represents exponentiation, which it does not.

You can fix the problem by either

```
amp = round (sine * pow(2.0, 31));   // all floating point
```

or

```
amp = round (sine * (1UL << 31));
```

The second computes `1` leftshifted 31 bits as an `unsigned long` (which is guaranteed able to represeny the result, unlike `unsigned` or `int` for which there is not such a guarantee).   Then, in doing the multiplication, it promotes that value to `long double`.

If you are doing predominantly floating point operations, the first is more understandable to people who will maintain such code.   The second is probably rather cryptic to someone who writes numeric code but is not well acquainted with bit fiddling operations - as, ironically, you have demonstrated in your belief that `^` is exponentiation.

You would need to test to determine which option offers greater performance (given the need to convert `unsigned long` to `long double` in the second , and potential for `std::pow()` in the first to be optimised for some special cases).   In other words, there is potential for the compiler optimiser to get aggressive in both cases, or for the implementation of `pow()` to be lovingly hand-crafted, or both.